# Facebook login/connect help - PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

I am having problems with Facebook connect.
Once I have the connect with Facebook button how do i retrieve the info with php?

There are loads of examples in developer.facebook.com but I couldn't get any of them to work.

Is it POST or GET or what? (I'm kinda new to php... )

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - **DEMO:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/facebook-login-connect-help-php/

---

1. **Setup** new App [here](http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php)
2. **Download** the PHP SDK [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)
3. **Copy & Paste** the code you'll find [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) into a file called `index.php`
4. **Edit** the first lines of the code above and provide the needed informations like below:

---

```
require 'sdk/facebook.php'; //the path to the downloaded PHP SDK    

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '105810212821284', //App ID you find once created the app
  'secret' => '3d6fdaa377cd4ca9...', //Secret Key you find once created the app
  'cookie' => true,
));
```

you have done ;)

---

**Application Settings:**

1. Web Site -> Site URL -> `http://so.devilmaycode.it/facebook/`
2. Web Site -> Site Domain -> `so.devilmaycode.it`
3. Facebook Integration -> Canvas URL -> `http://so.devilmaycode.it/facebook/`

**Requiriment**

1. PHP5
2. CURL Lib

**Check if you have the requirement**

```
<? echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

**Demo Source**

- http://pastebin.com/KyQ3CHV0

Comment: "Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 77: error setting certificate verify locations........" I just copied the code

Comment: I have the requirements, Application setting are pretty much the same.
Thank you so much for the help, can you help me fix it?

Comment: ok do the following, open the **facebook.php** search for `$CURL_OPTS` then add this option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,`

Comment: It works! Thanks.
I thought that was just junk (the file u said to download)

Comment: you welcome bro, pls can you tick the check icon in order to accept the answer? ;)

Comment: Can you post the code for your demo page? I am interested to see how you get javascript based login to work. On my end, when I click on login, it pops up a new window and window disappears right away. It doesn't seem that window.location.reload() was called at all. Doing traffic sniffing and trying to figure out what I did wrong. By the way, I have no trouble with PHP based login, but I do want a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

Example

```
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}
```

Display the data

```
echo $me['email']
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

More info about [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Answer (score 0):

To get the email or aditional data from users, you need to request it first(if not you only can get the basic data, like name / picture or only the public data), check the api facebook file in the function called "getLoginUrl".

```
'api_key'         => $this->getAppId(),
'cancel_url'      => $currentUrl,
'display'         => 'page',
'req_perms'      => 'email',  <------------- email
'fbconnect'       => 1,
'next'            => $currentUrl,
'return_session'  => 1,
'session_version' => 3,
'v'               => '1.0',
```